# custom User Notification on different errors

Tags: jenkins

sometimes a Jenkins Pipline fails because some service is down.
Error message is something like: "hudson.AbortException: Node xxx failed with message .. no files to archive found..."

sometimes it is a real problem because of the artifact under test is not good.

I want to filer out the infrastructure problems and give the user a solution, e.g.
if the error message containts these strings and patterns then tell him: probably its not your fault, solution is to retrigger something or call for help

How would i do this?

thanks a lot

Comment: [Build Failure Analyzer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-failure-analyzer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is caused at a certain stage, you can capture it and then send an email, slack message or even trigger another execution based on it's content :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh 'command_that_fails'
                }
                script {
                    if (error) {
                        echo "Error message: ${error}"
                        callYourActionHere(someParameter) 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also the stage has a "failure" post step that you can use to apply logic to the failures scenarios:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            failFast true
            steps {
                sh 'command_that_may_fail'
                sh 'another_command_that_may_fail'
            }
            post {
                failure {
                    echo "Build failed due to an error in the build step"
                    callSomeMethod( someparameter )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'run_tests'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if you act on the errors I strongly recommend to add friendly console messages .